# AJAX Control Toolkit HTMLEditor styling being partially stripped on page_load

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

So I have an HTMLEditor and it is correctly saving HTML to the database as follows:

```
    <span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 36pt; font-weight: bold;">This is a test</span><span style="color: #ff0000;"><br />
 <br />
 </span><span style="color: #0000ff;">New Line. New ckolor</span>
```

This results in large, red, bold text that reads "This is a test" and smaller, blue, bold text that reads "New Line. New ckolor". (It's all one line in the database field, stack overflow is formatting the above code oddly"

Once saved, I refresht eh page, and checking to see if there's something in that database field, if so, assign it to the textbox:

```
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type.TaskDescriptionText))
        {
            tbTaskDescription.Content = type.TaskDescriptionText;
        }
```

I can put a break point here and check. THe TaskDescriptionText property does in fact still have the complete style line: style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 36pt; font-weight: bold;"

It is assigned to the .Content property of the TaskDescription editor, but somehow when the page is done loading, only 'style="color: #ff0000;"' remains for the first span, and 'style="color: #0000ff;"' for the second. In other words, anything after the color for style, is stripped and is not added as a style on the element.

I searched my entire solution and cannot find ANYWHERE else server side that messes with the content of this box, so once it's assigned, it should not change! Unless the html editor itself is doing something?

Comment: Also, i would like to note, that as a test, i put an <asp:Label> that reads from the same database field, and assigns the label.Text to it. the result is, the HTMLEditor fails to render all of the styling assigned to it's .Content, but the label has no problem displaying all of the stuff in .Text, including all of the styling. =(

Definitely seems to be an issue ONLY with the htmleditor's .Content.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would HTMLEncode the text before saving it to the database and HTMLDecode the text when you read it from db. This will save you many problems.